# Reducing RAM usage of numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to convert my dataframe to numpy arrays using pd.values.

```
train.shape
(20125605, 12)
test.shape
(41697600, 12)
x_train = train.values
x_test = test.values
```

This is taking up a lot of space in my RAM. Is there some way I can reduce this?

Note: I need to feed this data into an RNN

Comment: Does using `.to_numpy()` instead of `.values` help?  That's what the docs recommend, and it might avoid a copy.

Comment: Check your array data types. That could be the best way to reduce memory usage.

Comment: What's the `dtypes` of the frame?  or the `info` disolay?